# How do i display images stored as blob data type in mysql with php?

Tags: php, html, image, blob, jpeg

How do i display an image stored in mySQL database as BLOB  ?
What it tried so far:
 1. Created a new php function/file to get picture (getpicture.php).
 2. In the html, I have the following code:

```
<img src="getpicture.php?id=2" border ="0" height="250" width="250" /> 




/*below is the getpicture.php*/
<?php

@ $db = new MySQLi('localhost','root','','myDatabase');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

if(isset($_GET['People_Id'])) {

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['People_Id']);
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'people' WHERE 'People_Id' = '$id'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $imageData =$row['image'];
    }

    header("content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $imageData;
    echo $id;
}

else {
    echo "Error!";
    echo $id;
}

?>
```

**What's wrong with the codes ? Please help!**

Comment: You're treating your table and column as values; remove the quotes.

Comment: This `SELECT * FROM 'people' WHERE 'People_Id'` remove all the single quotes or use backticks `\``

Comment: Also remove the quotes from `'$id'` if `People_Id` is a numeric field.

Comment: You're also not passing DB connection to your `$id`

Comment: And remove the `@` from the db initialisation, it suppresses errors.

Comment: And `mysqli_real_escape_string` does **not** prevent injection, you're code is vulnerable. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Some actually like getting "injections". Depends which part of town one is in. +1

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Not a bad error count for ~20 lines of code. _Sigh_.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Which is why I don't post "answers" for questions like these; just comments. Fish and birds like worms, not me. ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I hear you. I notice you didn't pick up on my incorrect use of `you're` though... To late to edit. ;)

Comment: **facepalm** - Oh... you're sneaky. lol @TheBlueDog Testing if I was paying attention eh? haha!

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It gets worse - `**to** late to edit`. Time to knock it on the head, methinks.

Comment: @TheBlueDog youthinks eh? metoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question, it's working now..

Below is the getpicture.php:

```
<?php

$db = new MySQLi('localhost', '', '', 'mydatabase');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed: '. $db->connect_error;
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = "SELECT `Picture` FROM member WHERE `Id` = '$id'";

$result = $db->query($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $imageData = $row['Picture'];
    header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
    echo $imageData;
}
```

}
?>

The php script which retrieve the getpicture.php above looks like this:

```
echo '<img src="getpicture.php?id=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]) . '"border ="0" height="250" width="250" />';
```

**Thaank you all for the help**

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'people' WHERE 'People_Id' = '$id'");
```

you use wrong quotes for table name (must be backtick instead of single quote (see tylda ~ key). See docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Also this is wrong too

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $imageData;
echo $id;
```

get rid of last `echo $i;` and replace it with `exit();` otherwise you corrupt the image data stream you just sent.

Comment: I'm glad I didn't put in an "answer" *per se*. I would've been only 50% right.

Comment: *However;* *"must be backtick instead of single quote"* - The ***"must"*** part applies if using a reserved keyword, or contains a space as a word seperator, or a (hyphen) minus sign (treated as doing math/substraction). Although it is good practice to do so. *Oh,* and you missed [`one`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209913/how-do-i-display-images-stored-as-blob-data-type-in-mysql-with-php#comment39263517_25209913) ;)

Comment: I fixed all the wrong codes according to your suggestions above. It's one step closer to display image from mySQL with blob data type. Now, it's display an icon ( a little image icon with teared-up on right bottom corner) as if php can't retrieve any data from database. I store the .jpg image in mySQL as BLOB data type in 'Image' column name. Any clues why it's doing this ???

Answer (score 0):

Plenty is wrong.

1. your SQL is wrong. Remove the single quotes from the table and column and replace with back ticks.
2. Although it may still work, you should have a couple of new lines after your header
3. You shouldn't echo out your $id after you echo your image data.
4. You're checking for the wrong value when you check isset
5. Also, you should be using OOP for mysqli
6. Since your image data is only a single row, you don't need to wrap it in a while loop

Here is an updated code example

```
<?php

$db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'myDatabase');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connection to database failed: '. $db->connect_error;
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `People_Id` = '$id'");

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $imageData = $row['image'];

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n");
    echo $imageData;
}

else {
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Comment: Although you did fix the `real_escape` issue amongst many; it wasn't mentioned in the enumeration of errors. As per [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209913/how-do-i-display-images-stored-as-blob-data-type-in-mysql-with-php#comment39263517_25209913) - Yet this looks good to go ;)

Comment: I fixed all the wrong codes according to your suggestions above. It's one step closer to display image from mySQL with blob data type. Now, it's display an icon ( a little image icon with teared-up on right bottom corner) as if php can't retrieve any data from database. I store the .jpg image in mySQL as BLOB data type in 'Image' column name. Any clues why this happens ???