# Image is broken when retrieved as blob image from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I am getting broken image everytime. please help me with this i am new to php. imagedata is column of blob type in my table named property, my calling function in file print.php as shown below

```
/*This is image.php file*/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = " ";
$dbname = "nevin";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) 
 {
//If not isset -> set with dumy value 
$_GET['id'] = "undefine"; 
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}
$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM property where id = '$id'"); 
if($image) 
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image=$image['imagedata'];/*imagedata is column of blob type in my table       named property*/
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');/* in my database i have images in jpg  format and i am storing images as blob datatype*/
echo $image;
?>


<img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>
/*this is my calling function in file print.php as shown below*/

/*print.php*/
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = " ";
 $dbname = "Nevin";

 // Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM property";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>


<section>
    <div class="features">
     <div class="l-container">
    <div class="content-wrap clearfix align-center">


        <?php



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {

       echo '<div class="grid">';?>
            <img src="image.php? id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" /><?php 
            echo '<h2>'.$row["id"].'</h2>'.
            '<p>'. $row["city"]. " " . $row["price"].'</p>'.
           '</div>';

          }
?>            
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Check this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209913/how-do-i-display-images-stored-as-blob-data-type-in-mysql-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<img src="image.php? id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />
```

to

```
<img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
```